# Format float variable output in c++ using std::ofstream

Tags: c++, floating-point, format, ofstream

I have the following code:

```
std::ofstream myfile;
std::stringstream filename3;
myfile.open("results.txt");

myfile << "precision= " << precision << "\n";
```

And the output in my file is formatted like this:

```
precision= 5.96e-07...
```

How can I print the numeric value as a number instead of a numeric value expressed using e?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use stream manipulator [`fixed`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed):

```
myfile << "precision= " << std::fixed << precision << "\n";
```

You might also want to use [`setprecision`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision) to adjust the number of decimal digits.